# Capture section of string between two underscores using sed

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed, capture

I have a list of strings in the following format (the xxx can be any alpha-numeric character):

> *xxx_xxx_ab_abcyyy_xxx_xxx:*
>
> *xxx_xxx_jkl_mnoyyy_xxx_xxx:*
>
> *xxx_xxx_abcyyy_xxx_xxx:*

I am trying to use sed to capture the section after the second '_' until the end of the section ending in yyy, whether there's an additional portion (like the *ab* and *jkl*) or not.

I am using the following command:

```
sed -r 's/.*_(.+yyy)_.*:/\1 /':
```

But I keep getting the whole string.
The ideal output would be (for these three strings of the example):

> ab_abcyyy
>
> jkl_mnoyyy
>
> abcyyy

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `sed -E 's/^([^_]*_){2}(.*yyy)_.*/\2/'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following. Considering that your Input_file is of same pattern of shown samples.

```
sed 's/\([^_]*\)_\([^_]*\)_\(.*yyy\).*/\3/'  Input_file
```

Comment: I would combine yours and the answer by @MichalTurczyn .

Comment: Thanks, @RavinderSingh13! Your solution worked fine. I just had to take off the slashes because it was blocking the reference in the shell script and I am using the -r option of sed as well.

Comment: You should be aware the `.*` is greedy and so will match the longest string possible i.e. `sed 's/.*yy/X&X/' <<<'abcyydefyy' ` will match the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern: `([a-zA-Z0-9]+_){2}([a-zA-Z0-9_]*yyy)[a-zA-Z0-9_]*:`. Second capturing group (`\2`) is what you need.

`([a-zA-Z0-9]+_){2}` will ensure, that you will first catch two sections and start capturing group right after that, until you meed `yyy`.

Try [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oul8OP/1).